# Docker Can't Find = in "ENV" Must be of the form: name=value

Tags: docker, dockerfile, devops

New to the world of docker, my dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM base
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

ENV NPM_VERSION=6.4.1 \
    IONIC_VERSION=3.19.0 \
    CORDOVA_VERSION=9.0.0 \

# Install NuGet CLI
ENV NUGET_VERSION=4.7.0
```

It looks like I'm specifying the env variables correctly with name=value...is this a red herring? What looks wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
ENV NPM_VERSION=6.4.1
ENV IONIC_VERSION=3.19.0 
ENV CORDOVA_VERSION=9.0.0
```

or

```
ENV NPM_VERSION=6.4.1 IONIC_VERSION=3.19.0 CORDOVA_VERSION=9.0.0
```

I think multiple env variables with new lines are not valid syntax.

Comment: Multiple env variables with new lines *are* valid syntax, but the last line must not end with a backslash

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple ENV but not necessory. docker do support new lines

```
ENV NPM_VERSION=6.4.1 \
    IONIC_VERSION=3.19.0 \
    CORDOVA_VERSION=9.0.0 \ #you get extra \ here
```

should be

```
ENV NPM_VERSION=6.4.1 \
    IONIC_VERSION=3.19.0 \
    CORDOVA_VERSION=9.0.0
```